# Can't pass XML using WSDL and escaping characters

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wsdl

I'm really struggling to find a way to pass an XML string without escaping the characters in C#.  I have a string below that needs to be passed into a call to a WSDL as a string.

```
<MyElement ElementId='xxxxxx'><Segments><Segment Status='1' SegmentId='xx1'/><Segment Status='1' 
SegmentId='xx2'/></Segments></MyElement>
```

If I try to pass it has a string the characters are escaping characters such as '>'.  I imported the WSDL in a .NET Console application. Here is what that string above is going into as I see using the Wizdler tool in chrome.

[image]

The entire message is this.

[image]

So my question is how in C# can I use the WSDL or even just do it manually to make the call to make this work

```
using (var client = new MemberService.MemberWebServiceSoapClient())
 {               
   var xml = "<MyElement ElementId='xxxxxxx'><Segments><Segment Status='1' SegmentId='xx1'/><Segment 
   Status='1' SegmentId='xx2'/></Segments></MyElement>"
   var send = client.Moving(xml);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Xml Linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string envelope = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                              "<Envelope xmlns=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                                 "<Body>" +
                                    "<Moving xmlns=\"http://www.retalix.com/HQLWebServices\">" +
                                    "</Moving>" +
                                 "</Body>" +
                              "</Envelope>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(envelope);
            XElement moving = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Moving").FirstOrDefault();
            XNamespace ns = moving.GetDefaultNamespace();
            string elementId = "xxxxxx";
            List<Segment> segments = new List<Segment>() {
                new Segment() { id = "xx1", status = 1},
                new Segment() { id = "xx2", status = 1}
            };

            XElement xMyElement = new XElement(ns + "MyElement", new XAttribute("ElementId", elementId));
            moving.Add(xMyElement);
            XElement xSegments = new XElement(ns + "Segments");
            xMyElement.Add(xSegments);

            foreach (Segment segment in segments)
            {
                XElement xSegment = new XElement("Segment", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("Status", segment.status),
                    new XAttribute("SegmentId", segment.id)
                });
                xSegments.Add(xSegment);
            }

            string sendXml = doc.ToString();
        }
    }
    public class Segment
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; }
    }
}
```